# Error in Enum while Updating to React 17,

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, eslint

I was updating my code from "react": "^16.12.0" -> "react": "^17.0.1" and was forced to update es-lint from "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0" -> "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0" and this es-lint update is point `enums` as no-use-var. is there any solution expect for disabling the es-lint.

https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg

```
enum NEW_ENUM {
    numEnum1 = 'numEnum1',
    numEnum2 = 'numEnum2',
    numEnum3 = 'numEnum3',
}

export {NEW_ENUM}


> src/modules/smart-memberships/translations/type2.ts   Line 1:6: 
> 'NEW_ENUM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars   Line 2:5: 
> 'numEnum1' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars   Line 3:5: 
> 'numEnum2' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars   Line 4:5: 
> 'numEnum3' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
> 
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this will disable the no-used-var rule in entire application; this sounds like a patch not a solution; the actual question is why enum are detected as no-used-var; though they are used somewhere or the other in the application

Comment: _"this will disable the no-used-var rule"_ no it won't, it will enable the TypeScript-aware equivalent eslint rule. The non-TypeScript-aware version of `no-used-var` reports an error because it doesn't know how to process the TypeScript syntax for enums.